# Specific average calculation

Tags: average

Suppose I have a set of weighted grades for a subject in high school. Like this: `8.4 (weight: 3), 7.2 (weight: 1), 3.4 (weight: 3)`.
When I loop over that set like this:

```
totalCount: Double
totalWeight: Integer

for grade in grades {
  totalCount += grade * weight
  totalWeight += weight
}
average = totalCount / totalWeight
```

That gives me the current average. Which is fine, but I want to calculate what grade I should score for a given weight to precisely get an average of `5.50`.

That means I only want to calculate what grade I should score, as the user chooses the weight.

That means I should use this equalization: `5.50 = ((grade1 * weight1) + (grade2 * weight2) .... + (gradeToBeCalculated * givenWeight))`.
I'm not entirely sure how to do this in programming code, has somebody got examples for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation above is a linear equation in many variables, as only the weights are fixed and all the grades can vary.

If you have ***n*** variables, you need to have ***n*** independent equations to get a unique solution. The equation you have will probably have infinite solutions. However, as the range for grades is probably limited, it may have a unique solution or no solution for particular values of the weights.

**EDIT**

The question asks for how to get an overall average of 5.50 when one grade and one weight is added.

For this:

$5.50$ $=$ $($$total count$(existing) $+$ $new grade$ $*$ $new weight$$)$ $/$ $($ $existing total weight$ $+$ $new weight$ $)$

Thus,

$new grade$ $=$ $($ $5.50$ $*$ $($ $existing total weight$ $+$ $new weight$ $)$ $-$ $total count$ $)$ $/$ $new weight$

Comment: The weight per grade can actually vary from 1..n, but it's fixed as in: it is set at a fixed value by a teacher. The grades are also fixed by the teacher.

The thing is, I want to add a grade to the equation as mentioned above, but I'm not sure how I should calculate what that grade should be with the weight given by the user.

Comment: So that means I calculate the given set of grades with weights, the user inputs a weight and I just need to calculate which grade that user should score on the next test to get a 5.50

Comment: You mean the data is added one at a time and you want to know what grade you need for a given weight in a _single_ test to make the overall value 5.50?

Comment: Precisely, yes. I want the grade of that single test calculated for the average to be at least 5.50.

Comment: I add one grade with the given weight and I want to know what value that grade should be in order for the average to be 5.50.

Comment: And any grade above this would only increase the average for a given weight

Comment: Amazing! I checked your solution and when I have a `5,7` with weight `3` already, when I use your formula for weight `1` I should score a `4,9`. When I use that in the basic formula to calculate my new average, it says `5,5`.

Thank you so much, GoodDeeds!

Comment: By the way, how does the formula respond when the average is lower than 5.50?
Will it also correctly produce the grade I need to score for my average to become a 5.50?

Comment: Yes it will. However, if it is impossible to score that high a grade (whatever you want), you will get it greater than the maximum value and if it is impossible to score that low a grade, you will get a negative answer.

Comment: Alright :) Then I can backup that I need the lowest value for a given grade and calculate again with the result from the first calculation, so being recursive.

Thanks so much :D